# how does fmap function composition works

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand how function composition works.

The common example is:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c  
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

It is easy to understand, what a function composition is.

Now consider:

```
(fmap . fmap) (+5) (Just (Just 4))
```

Let's consider first `fmap` implementation:

```
fmap . fmap = \x -> fmap ( fmap x )
```

How does the example is going to execute?

Does `fmap (+5)` is going to execute first?

What is the `x` value in connection of the example?

Comment: Your statement `fmap . fmap (+5) (Just (Just 4))` does not makes sense: the first `fmap` expects a function.

Comment: I edited to `(fmap . fmap) (+5) (Just (Just 4))` now it is obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(fmap . fmap) (+5) (Just (Just 4))
= { def. (.) }
fmap (fmap (+5)) (Just (Just 4))
= { fmap g (Just x) = Just (g x), where g = fmap (+5) ; x = Just 4 }
Just (fmap (+5) (Just 4))
= { fmap g (Just x) = Just (g x), where g = (+5) ; x = 4 }
Just (Just ((+5) 4))
= { def. (+) }
Just (Just 9)
```